# Connection String issue with inserting SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, connection-string, plesk

I am having some issues with inserting into my database. I'm hosting my website using Plesk and myLittleAdmin holds with my a SQL Server database.

The issues is that I can edit and delete items from a management page that shows all the items in the database, but as soon as I try add/insert an item into the database, I get this error

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The connection string 'WatchDBv2Entities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

When searching that people say I simply need to add `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` to `WatchDBv2Entities`, but no matter where I place it or what I do i still get errors.

Here is my connection string info:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WatchDBv2ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=IPaddressofDBserver;Initial Catalog=WatchDBv2;Integrated Security=False;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="WatchDBv2Entities"  
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.ModelPresentation.csdl|res://*/App_Code.ModelPresentation.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.ModelPresentation.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=IPaddressofdbserver;initial catalog=WatchDBv2;integrated security=False;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a connection string for Entity Framework with an `.edmx` model file, you need to specify the `System.Data.EntityClient` as the provider - **not** `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Try this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WatchDBv2ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=IPaddressofDBserver;Initial Catalog=WatchDBv2;Integrated Security=False;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="WatchDBv2Entities"  
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.ModelPresentation.csdl|res://*/App_Code.ModelPresentation.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.ModelPresentation.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data  source=IPaddressofdbserver;initial catalog=WatchDBv2;integrated security=False;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />  <!-- add the "EntityClient" as the provider! -->
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Had one more after it but all I needed to do was add my User ID and Password to WatchDBv2Entities and everything worked perfectly.